# 404 redirect works but changes rewritten URL path in browser to full URL path

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I use a URL rewriting scheme of the following:

```
example.com/about/
example.com/this/is/a/page/
```

GOES TO:

```
example.com/pages/about/about.php
example.com/pages/this/is/a/page/page.php
```

It works fine, but on a 404 error, when typing in `example.com/badpage/` it shows 404 page but changes the URL string to `example.com/pages/badpage/badpage.php`.

How to do keep the URL the same even on a 404 error?

(The htaccess also adds on '/' to the end of the URL requested as you can see from the code below)

---

*htaccesss code:*

```
DirectoryIndex /pages/index/index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/error/404.php

RewriteEngine On

#Removes the www from domain for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.portal\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://portal.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Don't fix direct file links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://portal.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$    pages/$1/$1.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$    pages/$1/$2/$2.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$    pages/$1/$2/$3/$3.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$    pages/$1/$2/$3/$4/$4.php    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add conditions before each of your rewrites to ensure you're not blindly rewriting into a file that doesn't exist. Mainly, the 4 rules at the end need to have some conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%1/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/%1.php [NC,L]
```

The first condition creates a grouping which is backreferenced using `%1`. The second condition creates a path that you are trying to rewrite to and checks if that file exists using `-f`. Same thing for the others:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%1/%2/%2.php -f
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/%2/%2.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%1/%2/%3/%3.php -f
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/%2/%3/%3.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%1/%2/%3/%4/%4.php -f
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/%2/%3/%4/%4.php [NC,L]
```